# How to replay some code/action after an observable retry (retry, retryWhen) succeeded?

Tags: typescript, websocket, rxjs, rxjs-observables

My case, I have a retry stuff on WebSocket Observable that works with use of `retryWhen` and `delayWhen`.
And I have to replay init message to the server when the connection is up again.

I can't find a way to do that.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you please add what you tried until now, and a part of the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.